# How to Automatically Change a Local Variable within a Function in R?

Tags: r

To simplify the question, I will use a toy example here. I want to derive the gradient and Hessian of a polynomial function such as
    library(pracma)

```
dummy <- function(x) {
         z <- x[1]; y <- x[2]
         rez <- (z^2)*(y^3)+3
         rez
         }
grad(dummy, c(1,2))

hessian(dummy, c(1,2))
```

M question is that is there an efficient way so I can derive the gradient and Hessian from different constant terms in `dummy`? e.g., the gradients and Hessians from `(z^2)*(y^3)+a` at `z=1` and `y=2`, where `a=[0.01,3]`.

Thanks!

Comment: Kinda like Cholesky decomposition `PP'`, but I set one of the upper triangular elements as -0.0005 (non-zero).

Comment: The logic is very simple---I use optimization skill to guess which are the most likely values for the elements `P_{11},P_{21},P_{22},P_{31},P_{32},P_{33}`. However, even you do not agree with this algorithm, my main issue is that I want to get these values under different settings of the element `P_{23}`, and apparently I have not figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Does the question make more sense now? Thanks for the suggestion @ZheyuanLi.

Comment: `a` is `3` in `rez` within the function. My issue is that I want to keep changing the constant term, for example between 0 to 3, to see the change of gradient and Hessians under different conditions.

Comment: That's a typo. Arbitrarily choosing an interval for `a` within `[0.01,3]`. I just edited it.

Comment: AFAIR calculus, the constant term `+ 3` (intercept) has no effect on the gradient or partial derivatives. So, it doesn't matter if `a` is 0.01 or 3. Or, did I miss the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `pracma::hessian` and `pracma::grad` take `...` as "variables to be passed to `f`". If you want `a` to be a variable, you just need your `dummy` function to take it as an argument:

```
dummy <- function(x, a) {
         z <- x[1]; y <- x[2]
         rez <- (z^2)*(y^3)+a
         rez
         }

grad(dummy, c(1,2), a = 0.01)
# [1] 16 12
hessian(dummy, c(1,2), a = 3)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   16   24
# [2,]   24   12

sapply(seq(0.01, 3, length.out = 10), function(a) grad(dummy, c(1, 2), a = a))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]   16   16   16   16   16   16   16   16   16    16
# [2,]   12   12   12   12   12   12   12   12   12    12
```

Of course the results are all the same, you are changing a constant term and then taking derivatives; the derivative of any constant is 0. But the idea will generalize to more interesting cases.